# folium timeslider doesn't remove previous added marker in the map

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to plot markers using time slider. I have created timestamped geojson as follows:

```
def create_geojson_features(df):

    features = []
    for lat,lan,intensity,time in zip(df['latitude'],df['longitude'],df['intensity'],df['timestamp']): 
        time = str(time)
        feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'Point', 
                'coordinates':[lan,lat]
            },
            'properties': {
                'time': time,
                'style': {'Color' : color(intensity)},
                'icon': 'Marker',
                'color':color(intensity),
                'iconstyle':{
                    'Color': color(intensity),
                    'fillOpacity': 0.8,
                    'stroke': 'true',
                    'radius': 7
                }
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)
    return features
features = create_geojson_features(df)
```

Here is my code to plot the markers

```
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
m = folium.Map([latmean,lonmean], zoom_start=11)

TimestampedGeoJson(
        {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features}
        , period='PT1H'
        , add_last_point=False
        , auto_play=False
        , loop=False
        , max_speed=1
        , loop_button=True
        , date_options='YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        , time_slider_drag_update=True
    ).add_to(m)
```

I have specified period as PT1H, as I scroll the slider the new points keep on adding. How can I remove old points and show new points only? Please help.

Comment: Same issue here, hoping for a solution

Comment: I figured out a workaround, Change parameters on timestamped_geojson.py

Comment: @gokyori can you share what did you change in the parameters of timestamped_geojson,py to be able to clear plots between timestamps? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a parameter just for that: duration = 'P1D'

With your example, and to only display per timestamp:

```
TimestampedGeoJson(
        {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features}
        , period='PT1H'
        , duration='PT1H'
        , add_last_point=False
        , auto_play=False
        , loop=False
        , max_speed=1
        , loop_button=True
        , date_options='YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        , time_slider_drag_update=True
    ).add_to(m)
```

Comment: One other thing to add:

When using the duration, I ran into cases where the previous day would still appear. For example if your period is set to 'P1D' and duration set to 'P1D' some of the data from the previous day will still show up on the map.

To avoid this use:
period = 'P1D',
duration = 'P0D