# Only display marker at TimeStamp using Folium TimestampedGeoJson

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, folium

I am plotting ground tracks of a satellite using Folium's TimestampGeoJson plugin. I am able to plot the animated markers, but would like to only display the marker at timestamp. I want the previous markers to disappear, and only have one marker shown on the map at a time, to create the illusion of the satellite moving around the map.
Here is the code I use to generate the map:

```
import folium
import webbrowser
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson


def generate_map(latlon_list, geojson_data):

    my_map = folium.Map(location=[0,0], height=1000, width=1000, zoom_start=2, 
      min_zoom=2, max_zoom=12, max_bounds=True, no_wrap=True)
    map_name = "folium_1000_1000_map.html"
    tgj = TimestampedGeoJson(geojson_data, period="PT1M", add_last_point=False)
    my_map.add_child(tgj)
```

This generates the following:
[image]

I want the animation to only display one marker at a time. Here is a [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909832/folium-timeslider-doesnt-remove-previous-added-marker-in-the-map) to a similar question I have found, but none of the answers mentioned there have the effect I want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer lies in the [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909832/folium-timeslider-doesnt-remove-previous-added-marker-in-the-map) question, i just added:

```
tgj = TimestampedGeoJson(satellite["geojson_data"], period="PT1M", duration="PT1M", add_last_point=False)
```

To my TimestampedGeoJson object, and voila ! Only markers at timestamp will be displayed now. The important option here is the `duration` one.